# If/Else calculations through JOptionPane

Tags: java, if-statement, joptionpane

I am trying to calculate this if/else statement through the JOption Message window. Prompt 1 is fine and returns the name, but I am not getting any calculations through prompt 2. I'm guessing I need to do something with my double number1, but I'm not exactly sure.

Thanks in advance!

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    Scanner imput = new Scanner(System.in);   //ALLOW USER TO INPUT NAME AND MONTHLY INCOME

    long monthlyIncome = 0;
    double newSocSecTax = 0.0;
    double oldSocSecTax = 0.0;

    String name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog( "Please enter your name: "); //PROMPT 1

    String income = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("\nPlease enter your gross monthly income:  "); //PROMPT 2
    double number1 = Double.parseDouble( income );

    if(monthlyIncome >= 110100.00)
    {
       newSocSecTax = 110100.00 * .062;
       oldSocSecTax = 106800.00 * .042;
    }
    else
    {
       if(monthlyIncome >= 106800.00)
       {
         newSocSecTax = monthlyIncome * .062;
         oldSocSecTax = 106800.00 * .042;
       }
   else
   {
       newSocSecTax = monthlyIncome * .062;
       oldSocSecTax = monthlyIncome * .042;
   }
   }


   String message = String.format( "%s, your monthly social security tax will be $%.2f." +
                                 "\nThis is an increase of $%.2f.", name, newSocSecTax, oldSocSecTax );

   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog( null, message );
   System.exit(0);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code to

```
double monthlyIncome = Double.parseDouble( income );
```

because in `if-else` statement you are using `monthlyIncome` but in your original code you assigned the value to `number1`

Comment: When I do this it says that monthlyIncome is already defined. I had set that to 0 up above so that I can capture the user's data.

Comment: Actually, this did the trick.  I needed to delete the monthlyIncome variable at the top. Thank you very much for the help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have a value in `monthlyIncome`, you parse the input into `number1`. This leaves `monthlyIncome` at `0`, making the tax variables also `0`.

Note that it's helpful to describe what's actually happening versus what you expect to happen, otherwise we're forced to guess what you mean by "not getting any calculations". Of course you're getting calculations--the problem is that they're not what you want.

Comment: Sorry about the lack of clarity. I am a novice when it comes to programming (obviously) and I meant to say that the prompt 2 calculations are returning as $0.00. 

How do I take the string the user inputs and use that in a calculation? I have the double.parsedouble, but I'm not sure what I need to do to get that user input to be calculated correctly.

Comment: I finally figured it out. Just needed to change number1 to monthlyIncome and delete the monthlyIncome variable at the top. Sorry again for lack of clarity and thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

you haven't set monthlyIncome to be anything based on the number1 returned through the "prompt".

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to assign `number1` to `monthlyIncome`, don't you? You're not using `number1` thus far and `monthlyIncome` will still have the value `0` after the user entered the number.

Keep in mind that `monthlyIncome` is a `long` variable and thus assigning `number1` will require a cast and might result in precision losses (if the user enters fractions), although those might be acceptable in your case.